# Python C API call to error() binds to libc implementation instead of a local one

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, libc, python-c-api

## EDITTED

See at end of post for edit in response to [Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51645267/4467301)'s comment

#### Disclaimer

Before going forward, I know that naming a function `error` is generally bad practice since it may clash with a similar function in libc, but this is an issue I have with some third-party software on which I have little control.
Plus I would really like to understand where this error comes from :-)

## The issue

The problem I have is that the code below, when executed through the Python interpreter instead of calling my local implementation of the `error` function, is actually calling the libC's `error` function instead (as shown by GDB's stack trace below).

When simply compiling the same code within another C program, I do not have such issues. Does someone knows where that comes from ? Does it have to do with the way Python loads shared libraries ?

## MCVE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* call_error(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
     {"error", call_error, METH_NOARGS, "call error"},
     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef module_defs = {
     PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
     "Test", "Test", -1, module_methods, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

PyObject* PyInit_Test(void)
{
     PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&module_defs);
     return module;
}

void error(const char* fmt, ...);

PyObject* call_error(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
     error("Error!");
     Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

void error(const char* fmt, ...)
{
     va_list ap;
     va_start(ap, fmt);
     vprintf(fmt, ap);
     va_end(ap);
}
```

## GDB output

Here is the output of importing running the above code within GDB using `python3 -c "import Test; Test.error()"`

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from python3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r -c 'import Test; Test.error()'
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import Test; Test.error()'
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
/usr/bin/python3:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strchrnul_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strchr.S:32
32  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strchr.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  __strchrnul_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strchr.S:32
#1  0x00007ffff6c2c432 in __find_specmb (format=0x4 <error: Cannot access memory at
#     address 0x4>) at printf-parse.h:108
#2  _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7fffffffae60, format=0x4 <error: Cannot access memory at 
#     address 0x4>, ap=0x7fffffffd5b0) at vfprintf.c:1320
#3  0x00007ffff6c2f680 in buffered_vfprintf (s=s@entry=0x7ffff6fbd680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>,
#     format=format@entry=0x4 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x4>,
#     args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd5b0) at vfprintf.c:2329
#4  0x00007ffff6c2c726 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff6fbd680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>,
#     format=format@entry=0x4 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x4>, 
#     ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffd5b0) at vfprintf.c:1301
#5  0x00007ffff6cef9bb in error_tail (status=status@entry=-161613509, 
#     errnum=errnum@entry=0, message=message@entry=0x4 <error: Cannot access memory at 
#     address 0x4>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd5b0) at error.c:271
#6  0x00007ffff6cefb3d in __error (status=-161613509, errnum=0, message=0x4 
#     <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x4>) at error.c:321
#7  0x00007ffff65df82e in call_error (self=0x7ffff67f3548, args=0x0) at test.c:24
#8  0x00000000004c5352 in _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords ()
#9  0x000000000054ffe4 in ?? ()
#10 0x00000000005546cf in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#11 0x000000000054fbe1 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000550b93 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#13 0x000000000042c4ca in PyRun_SimpleStringFlags ()
#14 0x0000000000441918 in Py_Main ()
#15 0x0000000000421ff4 in main ()
```

## EDIT

I did think about the `dlopen` issue with importing Python modules and actually the following code compiles and runs just fine and prints out:

```
> ./main
Hi there
```

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef void*(*arbitrary)();

extern void error(const char* fmt, ...);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     void *handle;
     arbitrary my_function;

     handle = dlopen("./libtest.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
     if (!handle) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

     *(void**)(&my_function) = dlsym(handle,"foo");
     (void) my_function();

     // Note: binding using dlsym(handle, "error") works too

     dlclose(handle);
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

`test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

extern void error(const char* fmt, ...);
extern void foo(void);

void foo(void)
{
     error("Hi there\n");
}

void error(const char* fmt, ...)
{
     va_list ap;
     va_start(ap, fmt);
     vprintf(fmt, ap);
     va_end(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is an issue I have with some third-party software on which I have little control.

If you have sources for this third_party software, you can edit them, or use macro tricks to rename the function, e.g. `-Derror=foo_error`.

If you only have an archive library, use `objcopy --redefine-symbol ...`.

If you only have a shared library, I don't know of a workable solution.

> Does it have to do with the way Python loads shared libraries ?

Kind of. What's happening is that the dynamic loader resolves a reference to `error`  to the earliest *exported* definition of that function.

When you link `error` into your main `a.out`, that definition is the first in linker search order, so it "wins".

When you use `dlopen` to load `libfoo.so` which contains `error` (which is what Python does for `import`), that library is loaded *after* `libc.so.6`, which means that `libc.so.6` appears earlier in the loader search order, and its definition "wins".

You don't need Python to see this: write a trivial test that uses `dlopen`, and the same problem will show up in it.

**Update:**

> I had written a small test case

Your test case *does* confirm my answer. You probably didn't build it correctly.

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so test.c
$ gcc main.c -ldl
```

Here the "wrong" `error` is called because the order of library loading is: `a.out`, `libc.so.6`, *then* `libtest.so`:

```
$ ./a.out
./a.out: UH��H�=�: Unknown error 640192728
```

But what you probably did was this:

```
$ gcc main.c ./libtest.so -ldl
```

Here the order of library loading is `a.out`, `libtest.so` (because `a.out` *directly* depends on `libtest.so`), *then* `libc.so.6`, and the "right" `error` gets called:

```
$ ./a.out
Hi there
```

Comment: Actually I thought about the `dlopen` issue and I had written a small test case (see edited question) and that one does not fail.
But I guess I'll have to rename the `error` function somehow.

Comment: @Tachikoma Answer updated: you likely made a mistake in *building* your test.